# Build Spring Boot image with maven can not locate webapp resources

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven, buildpack

I have an webapp folder which is bundeled into the resources folder

```
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
    <targetPath>META-INF/resources</targetPath>
</resource>
```

i can run my app with spring-boot:run, i can run it in eclipse, i can even build a jar and it works.

But when i build an image with `mvn spring-boot:build-image` the webapp folder is not found. I just get white 404 pages.

so i added some log outputs in the `org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot`

which shows following difference:

When running the working jar with `-cp "myapp.jar;lib/*"` the jarResources contains myapp.jar which includes the jsf files

```
preResources:
mainResources:
file:/C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Temp/tomcat-docbase.8080.7308835034218946689/
classResources:
jarResources:
file:/C:/Users/myuser/Downloads/myapp-4.2.0.4-SNAPSHOT/myapp.jar
file:/C:/Users/myuser/Downloads/myapp-4.2.0.4-SNAPSHOT/lib/jsf-impl-2.2.14.jar
file:/C:/Users/myuser/Downloads/myapp-4.2.0.4-SNAPSHOT/lib/custom-faces-0.2.7.jar
file:/C:/Users/myuser/Downloads/myapp-4.2.0.4-SNAPSHOT/lib/primefaces-6.1.jar
file:/C:/Users/myuser/Downloads/myapp-4.2.0.4-SNAPSHOT/lib/swagger-ui-3.37.2.jar
postResources:
```

but when running the container the `/workspace` folder seems not to be in the search-paths

```
emf_1  | preResources:
emf_1  | mainResources:
emf_1  | file:/tmp/tomcat-docbase.8080.12873057264998195501/
emf_1  | classResources:
emf_1  | jarResources:
emf_1  | file:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/custom-faces-0.2.7.jar
emf_1  | file:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/primefaces-6.1.jar
emf_1  | file:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jsf-impl-2.2.14.jar
emf_1  | file:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/swagger-ui-3.37.2.jar
emf_1  | postResources:
```

the webapp layer is also used

```
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> EXPORTING
[INFO]     [creator]     Reusing layer 'paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates:helper'
[INFO]     [creator]     Reusing layer 'paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica:helper'
[INFO]     [creator]     Reusing layer 'paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica:java-security-properties'
[INFO]     [creator]     Reusing layer 'paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica:jre'
[INFO]     [creator]     Reusing layer 'paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica:jvmkill'
[INFO]     [creator]     Reusing layer 'paketo-buildpacks/executable-jar:classpath'
[INFO]     [creator]     Reusing layer 'paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot:helper'
[INFO]     [creator]     Reusing layer 'paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot:spring-cloud-bindings'
[INFO]     [creator]     Reusing layer 'paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot:web-application-type'
```

any ideas what's going wrong? Or can anybody point me to an example jsf project where build-image ist working?

Comment: Why do you have that configured `<resource> <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>   <targetPath>META-INF/resources</targetPath></resource>` ? What kind of packaging do you have defined in Maven?

Comment: jar, because war is not supported for build-image